# Jenkinsfile symbolic linked from another folder

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

My Jenkins is configured by administrators to use Jenkinsfile in my project folder.

Can this Jenkinsfile be a symbolic link to another file in the same repo?

I have many projects in this repo and would like to keep the same jenikins file by using sybmolic link.

I ask because I am getting following error:-

```
Obtained my-project-1/Jenkinsfile from git git@REDACTED.example.com:my-multi-proj.git

org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 1: unexpected token: .. @ line 1, column 1.
   ../../common/Jenkinsfile-dev-svc
   ^

1 error

    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:309)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addFatalError(ErrorCollector.java:149)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addError(ErrorCollector.java:119)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addError(ErrorCollector.java:131)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.addError(SourceUnit.java:349)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.transformCSTIntoAST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.parseCST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:191)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.parse(SourceUnit.java:233)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$1.call(CompilationUnit.java:189)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:966)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:626)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:602)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:579)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:323)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:293)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox$Scope.parse(GroovySandbox.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:142)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:127)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:563)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:515)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:336)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:107)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:449)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of attempting to symlink the default `Jenkinsfile` to another `Jenkinsfile`, you could simply use the [load step method](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-cps/#load-evaluate-a-groovy-source-file-into-the-pipeline-script) to load the other `Jenkinsfile`:

```
load('../../common/Jenkinsfile-dev-svc')
```

The path specified in the argument may need to be modified depending upon the previous steps retrieving code in the project workspace.

Comment: Is it possible to create soft/hard link for `../../common` into the current project as `./common` and then refer `load('./common/Jenkinsfile-dev-svc')` ?

Comment: @bhantol Probably not since that would evoke the same behavior you are currently experiencing but with extraneous code.